# Bootstrap "form-horizontal" and label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have troubles with creating a "form-horizontal" with bootstrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/frauger/jo0b6yod/

As you can see in the jsfiddle the label "date of birth" is not correctly aligned above the "date of birth select"

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-10" name="name" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthday" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Birthday</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap all of your existing `select divs` in a new container `div` that has the `form-group` class.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
         <select type="text" class="form-control" id="field-day" required>
             <option>DD</option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
         <select type="text" class="form-control" id="field-month" required>
             <option>MM</option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
         <select type="text" class="form-control" id="field-year" required>
             <option>YYY</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**working fiddle:** 
**http://jsfiddle.net/jo0b6yod/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Include the label within div tag, that should make the label within a block level, and takes of 100% of its parent.

ex:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div><label for="birthday" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Birthday</label></div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="year"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="month"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="day"/>
  </div>    
</div>
```